# Why isn't Class.new called?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to override `Class.new` so that I can see what classes are being created e.g.

```
class Class
  class << self
  alias new_orig new
  def new(*args)
    obj = new_orig *args
    print "created",obj,"\n"
    obj
  end
  end
end

class X
end
```

It doesn't print anything, but if I create class using Class.new it works

```
puts Class.new

created#<Class:0x8b75888>
#<Class:0x8b75888>
```

So why there is a difference between `class X` and `Class.new` ?

Comment: Don’t you mean “why *isn’t* `Class.new` called?”?

Answer (score 3):

To get the wanted effect, you could use [`Class#inherited`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-i-inherited):

```
class Class
  def inherited(subclass)
    puts "Created #{subclass}"
  end
end

class XX  #writes "Created XX"
end
```

Comment: @that is nice, thanks, but question is why there is a dyssymmetry between `class X` and `Class.new` ?

Comment: @AnuragUniyal That's a question for Matz ;)

Comment: @alex maybe I should file a bug :)